# Resizing listbox with Python Tkinter and grid layout manager

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a simple app with two side-by-side scrollable listboxes. I want them each to take up half the window irrespective of the window size. While my window is resizable, the listboxes remain the same size and just get centered horizontally in their respective halves. What am I doing wrong?

```
from Tkinter import *
import os
import sys

class ScrollableList(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, vscroll=True, hscroll=False):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grid(sticky=NSEW)
        if vscroll:
            self.vScrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient=VERTICAL)
            self.vScrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)
        if hscroll:
            self.hScrollbar = Scrollbar(self, orient=HORIZONTAL)
            self.hScrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=E+W)
        self.listbox = Listbox(self, selectmode=SINGLE)
        self.listbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
        if vscroll:
            self.listbox['yscrollcommand'] = self.vScrollbar.set
            self.vScrollbar['command'] = self.listbox.yview
        if hscroll:
            self.listbox['xscrollcommand'] = self.hScrollbar.set
            self.hScrollbar['command'] = self.listbox.xview
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=0)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=0)

class Application(Frame):

    @classmethod
    def main(cls):
        NoDefaultRoot()
        root = Tk()
        app = cls(root)
        root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        root.resizable(True, True)
        root.mainloop()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grid(sticky=NSEW)
        options = dict(sticky=NSEW, padx=3, pady=4)
        self.list1 = ScrollableList(self)
        self.list2 = ScrollableList(self)
        self.list1.grid(row=0, column=0, **options)
        self.list2.grid(row=0, column=1, **options)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(1, weight=1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Application.main()
```

Comment: That doesn't seem right. My understanding is the weights are supposed to take care of this. See the section on Handing Resize in the docs here: http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/grid.html It says nothing about manual event binding.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: that is not true, if by "bind" you are referring to binding to events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting to set the `sticky` attribute when adding the actual listbox to its parent, which would cause the edges of the listbox to "stick" to the edges of the area allocated for them.

```
self.listbox.grid(..., sticky="nsew")
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan, that's it!